# Unity string compression/encoding

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, compression

I've seen many android games made with unity which had some coded strings like this:

```
ad6dc9d41349fdc2b3c85f9dfa48a4ebd4accc7b457811e2bda0b7ea19e6a424e81f7a76d35a7bd2d3002ae4fcd95083d139fb34e6644575a797a798b423507c3b398e9fa8ca40db131d05040ca69b4b9bffc653ce568fc74296b2cd3c5d5aab9d3895a05b98bfe578f02384e714a26f08a7e97c8ba11f701084aea6e4625b948d8c76eb2d4c41cd667d61313666114fb28adc64c3a38ab2fcc17be89c55e210063ce66ea2edd84865da965563eb3fc967980fd38da5a4c70e3157417d44a44a8cb0e9ce9578569d32817d02dbf0761a94ce6eb021f55cf7098ad638ca24f9226c1b713eaac19ca673545da06bad7530a78aa90f7928bc7ad2c6b5a649765c7d5e27a9e238c4e425f56693188cffd223827b07613f5321e03627cb9b4446f49492b1aa282662c6256fa39264d6bb6115f970536868d5fdf5c30f27571b089055e102d1084f96d5be4bea1bae5b9c1548cdc4d5903947657a8045071317ed315d1d08c996d0f79ee93c6c2b80c9a0dfd9c114c46b3b3561a0226386ecb792bce4667ddaec8403aa3900c07883e82b8933b7731771f185f0ec7814018a4a262d41040f82bd923c1154d07c39947535ec03ad2cfad65a48c58c8e1cda7cd05d345342d9b5d5198b140154eb2466ca8c9fe0be89444ccba599f9b15e46556b2f99f7284f639ddcd80e64a8fa90088037666c63e9a171ad063de01b8d40a37c6ef4ba25011acaf427e454fe045c40f338b7fe36b4d3339ea471646dd523be7fa4f80695fe23f5347e939365cdefc7436b054ccaed279ae927e5599b5e6ea5b29890562232a35f8931a3db44fcabf8f368464cd9221c054ec605cacdd9c8ab9f286b296bcc4a55146c74feae7a6b87f337220c48a9d84199cb8b0e7c190332e4deb6bd49024bb04c2975f27862961470291bb16358047931a64fda7b584b357f4609ad0b2299dc186ac481ee9461a5f93f24e51fab8338c54c9f7a1b11f37db037983106c8907f9603d3ae972c62b2591a7f33697a8586973c62a1c69abce3cb31ed7a34ed58bb35b495963827c6840e99a0714719106980b55e13cdf7210b3b1e6ee2a3a8978207788e135b33b3c9259bf171fdb3c73cdd643c485c0d63b800b2900ae7d64d92125061b8ee0963cefd250e91e73da4ac64f5281808fd1916eaa9eb58f53d88f043236beed4d6fad37cc74aa86bddb5c912a7c226e06a18a93b3fcdf025ece7496d83bd67813c140ca1e935a74b1ffe564745d489ac3f242c958955c860f2353bdbf3d15075b98ebbc910889e884fd396f04824aae8b9e52491e32c6082e1f054ac0884395beb94f17ac28f400d767e6bacd11b9fe54420bc12186dc1b8771bf8a366d60a8a9452e247b1aef39000bdb85cf0587987ac5d7d2bde630b0803e7c8908f2c707dfef19125fa4ef90648921a7a2e492f28417ce665de01d8eba8bd71ac9dde3c0a155df5c0951cab3c3955e2e4b2b77059ace03fd0506151fb3899f95c35fd32d0161c87252fb8412395db8c79a684b09495415aa7b345b81fa295a24b951e851744f95d0d8c903bf54c54e5547a84dabbbaae2db66ed511c79dc1fe9fb0d442e10a90e78d4942ac03b6f8946c137d0a972c236dff24bd262743df5a735e646a6f3251c64b93ea75e9592ee814954696f1f9c7673ecb4dd49974da08a1e1e948af6119ef59766c611adf8486b47c9d8e08d99801877defd7266277ec0563483db512a354f218b5c562c489168c41545bba30c135aeb174b7029024b781034ed450379d6bbc6edb6216ea5ca7100b9ca5a3629722de9fc5d4ff3529a79b1c60a745248f2bdda9249e50bb6627b7fde58f2e3cc2cf1a11a86e1ed50f741c96c92f816341c1f9a0ffefb1e2e3ce7df0aa6eb5fa5aa4302686e3eae08feea8b20574c1918cf82ac057aeba1c684332d8cdd3b0a72204f1b7f5b1cfbd29b06a9bd4692632dc01f2a96ce7e22dc768a047e783d13991d3a0f365abefe2d4899c805e3a3b81fb9ec5b06e479c7fbb473b614652f710a042f372042ec51206f7992ffc27a66b9e1c14e45ce0e3341aea9d0e243454c6ebcf96006bb9
```

My question is how are these strings built?
Are they just compressed or encoded and how to actually use them in unity?
Is there any way to uncompress/generate them without using unity?

Edit: this string came from an android app's PackageName.xml file in its data folder in /data.
Other strings in the file are regular strings. But this one is named player data.

Comment: It's hex-encoded data, could be anything.  The decoded version seems pretty opaque, maybe an encrypted value?  You might want to try a bit more context (i.e., where exactly are these values coming from?).

Comment: @nemequ I added the information.

Comment: It could mean anything encoded or could be a unique key representing the player data ID on the server.Or could be the player public key for communication between the device and the server for encryption.

Comment: @fafase the game is totally playable in offline mode.

Comment: Values can be saved locally but in order to create connection to the server or game center, a key should be required. Nowadays, less game are playable offline but think Angry Birds, you can play offline but if there is a connection, your scores are sent to the leaderboards on the server.

Comment: @fafase you're right, but this string is named player data. And there is another one like this named gamedata. It's certainly some kind of game save data.